# Nested 'for' in app engine / django incorrect

Tags: python, django

I am obviously doing something wrong, but my 'simple' nested for loop doesn't quite work correctly

My python code is...

```
rrentalmasters = srentalmaster.readall()
for rm in rrentalmasters:
    rm.rentalrates = srentalrate.readformaster(rm.rentalmasterid)
    logging.error(rm.rentalmasterid.asstring)
    for rr in rm.rentalrates:
        logging.error(' - ' + rr.rentalrate.asstring)

outopt = {
    'rentalperiods': rrentalperiods,
    'rentalmasters': rrentalmasters
}
doRender(self, 'rentalpricelist.html', outopt)

Sample log would be 
1
- 10
- 20
-40
2
- 5
- 10
- 15 
and so on.
```

rentalrates is a list() of 1-5 rates for each rentalmaster item.  The logging shows the correct values for each item logged

my html is as follows...

```
<table class='fsgrid' width='100%'>
    {% for rm in rentalmasters %}
        <tr>
        <td>{{ rm.code }}</td>
        <td>{{ rm.model }}</td>
        {% for rr in rm.rentalrates %}
            <td>{{ rr.rentalrate.asstring }}</td>
        {% endfor%}        
        </tr>
    {% endfor%}
</table>

html output might look like
| 1 | model 1 |  5 | 10 | 15 |  # incorrect rates should be 10, 20 and 40
| 2 | model 2 |  5 | 10 | 15 |  # correct rates
```

rm.code and rm.model display correctly but rr.rentalrate.asstring only shows the values for the LAST rm record, all rows in the table show the same rates.

The examples of nested loops seem to indicate a known number of items in the nested list.  While I can assume 1..5 items, I cannot know.

Any thoughts for me?

Thanks
David

Comment: Is the problem with the templating or with the code?  (i.e. Are the logs what you'd expect?)

Comment: Does the behaviour change if you create explicit copies of the sublists, like `rm.rentalrates = list(srentalrate.readformaster(rm.rentalmasterid))` ?

Comment: the logs produced by the python code are exactly correct, with the correct 'rentalrates' shown.  The sets of rm.code and rm.model show correctly but their rental rates are all the same, those of the last rm record.

Comment: Still, the most likely explanation is that rm.rentalrates is referencing the same object in all rows. That's the reason I asked for a literal copy with list() on assignment to rule out this case.